# Python - Circular Shift Lists (but not the whole index)

Tags: python

so basically i want to make list shift left but only 1 digit from every index.
for example:
if i have this list `[123,45678,90]` i want to get this `[234,56789,1]`
another example just to make sure from this `[12,34,56]` i want to get this `[23,45,61]`

what ive done so far is

```
def main():
    lst_lenght = int(input("Enter the lenght of the list:")) #amount of indexes
    lst_elements = create_list(lst_lenght)
    print(lst_elements)
    
def create_list(y):
    lst = []
    for i in range(y):
        x = int(input('Enter the list elements:'))
        lst.append(x)
    return lst
```

then ive tried to do function that i will get the first digit of number(in every index)
after this i was just thinking removing the digit and placing it in the end of the index before it exept the first index which will go to the last one.

unfortunately i wasnt able to do it ive got stuck on this part, would love ur help, Thank you very much!!

Comment: this is quite "smelly": if you need to shift digits across numbers, maybe you'd better hold the numbers as strings, rather than `int` objects?

Comment: hmm, i was thinking about converting the int to str 

Comment: That's a good point.  Think about it this way.  (1) Convert each element to a string. (2) Remember the length of each string.  (3) ''.join all the strings.  (4) Rotate by `s = s[1:] + s[0]`.  (5) Partition it up by the lengths you already stored and convert back to integer.

Comment: Thanks ill try this

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list comprehension. Each element in the new list is defined by taking `item[1:]` (everything after the first digit in that item) plus `next_item[0]` (the first digit of the next item).

To do this, it's easier if you operate on it as a list of strings, and then convert back to integers to return.

```
def shifted_list(lst):
    str_lst = [str(x) for x in lst]
    str_lst_shifted_by_one = str_lst[1:] + [str_lst[0]]
    shifted_str_lst = [item[1:] + next_item[0] for item, next_item in zip(str_lst, str_lst_shifted_by_one)]
    return [int(x) for x in shifted_str_lst]

print(shifted_list([123,45678,90])) # [234, 56789, 1]
```

Comment: i wish id understand what you did there :) ,  im new to python doing "campus" course ( not an english course). on line 3 i never saw something like this [i][1:]

Comment: Can you say a bit about which parts are not clear to you? Also, if you're asking about homework, it's helpful to say so in the initial question, since then we can cater the response better. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2045611

Comment: thank you, the original question from the free course im doing,  but the elements was integers from 1-9 so it was simple and i was able to find solution.
i wanted to try somthing harder and shifting 1 digit of bigger integers to the left and to the right just for practicing more.
- as i said i never saw something like [1:] and never saw "zip"

Comment: @David first of all, I love to hear that you're challenging yourself beyond the course! It's a really great way to improve. Now, regarding your questions First of all, `x[1:]` returns x, but missing the first item. This works for lists and strings, and I use it for both in my answer. Second, `zip(lst1, lst2)` returns a list like this: `[ (lst1[0], lst2[0]), (lst1[1], lst2[1]), ...]`. In other words, the first item is a pair containing the first items from both list, and so on.

Comment: Here's how I use these in my solution. I first construct str_lst_shifted_by_one. If `str_lst` is `[a, b, c, d]`, then `str_lst_shifted_by_one` is `[b, c, d, a]`. Then I zip these lists together and iterate through them in the list comprehension, which allows me to use the `item` and `next_item` syntax. Let me know if any of this is still unclear!